# Exchange symbol on a foreign google map

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome, gis

is there a way to exchange the design of a google map, which I load from a foreign website. I mean e.g. can I exchange all instances of a used .png file, that are placed on the map using for example the chrome developer tools.
Or even more concrete: on [flightradar24.com](http://www.flightradar24.com) I want to exchange all the little yellow airplane icons by just a single red pixel, to make a screen recording of it. (the pixels will later be tracked using processing). If I look in chrome developer tools under "network" and filter for images, then I see the image, but I cannot find it in the "elements". I want to change this image just temporarily to make a video of the map, with the new image. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!
best
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this inside the console(replace the URL with a URL of an image that fits your needs)

```
get_sprite=function(){return 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png';}
```

Comment: SUPER! this works fine! thank you very much Dr. Molle!